# How Do I create a .a file in xcode 4

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I would like to make a .a file which can be used as a library which implements a UIview and it can be used in various projects just as a include ?

Answer (score 1):

For XCode 4 libraries / frameworks follow the links in [How to compile xcode4 project to use as framework in second project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6452508/how-to-compile-xcode4-project-to-use-as-framework-in-second-project).

In order ot have the projects within one workspace, which is more convenient (but I never had the time to try it out:-), you may have a look at [XCode 4 how to add an external project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5361288/xcode-4-how-to-add-an-external-project)

Answer (score 0):

Build the project , navigate to Derived data ( Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> DerivedData

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/yourlibrary.a
(for Debug scheme)
```

And if the scheme is set to 'Release', and if you are running on Device

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/{app name}/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/yourlibrary.a
```