# Get album artwork from ID3 tag/Convert function from Java to Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, taglib, albumart

I've got the following question to ask:

How do you compile taglib with an iOS application?

I'm a bit confused as I added the folder into my project, tried to compile it, but instead it failed with 1640 errors.

How do I make it successfully compile - the reason why I ask is taglib allows for the extraction of album artwork from a tag.

If anyone knows an Objective-C based album artwork extraction class it would help - I don't know why Apple don't add a way of doing this in Core Foundation - because there are methods for extracting some of the data from an ID3 tag.

I can't see why there isn't *some* Objective-C way of doing it.

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:

After hours upon hours of trying to do this, I've found a Java function [here](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-retrieve-ID3-art-Image-from-an-mp3-file/td-p/352664) that seems to do the job fine, but I haven't got a *clue* on how to convert it to Objective-C (or let alone C++ for that matter), as its types seem to be completely different from those that are in Objective-C/C++. 
If anyone knows of a way to convert this it would **really** help, as this seems as my last option as I've tried so many others.

Comment: What kind of errors? Are you sure they are not jsut related to header fiel search path or similar issues?

Comment: Did you actually try following the discussion I linked to in my second comment below? It clearly demonstrates how to access ID3 information using only Apple's frameworks.

Comment: Yes, I did, and successfully got artist, album and song title information for it. I was also able to log the contents of the tag, but there's no constant for album artwork. So somehow I've got to process the raw ID3 tag, and find the image in there somehow. That's the bit I don't have a clue about.

Comment: As per your link above to the Java code; there is nothing listed there that is specific to Java and should be fairly trivial for any relatively experienced C programmer to convert. All it is doing is parsing the MP3 file at the byte level, using the file format documented [here](http://www.id3.org/id3v2.3.0)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
- (void)loadArtworksForFileAtPath:(NSString *)path completion:(void (^)(NSArray *))completion
{
    NSURL *u = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AVURLAsset *a = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:u options:nil];
    NSArray *k = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"commonMetadata", nil];

    [a loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:k completionHandler: ^{
        NSArray *artworks = [AVMetadataItem metadataItemsFromArray:a.commonMetadata
             withKey:AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork keySpace:AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon];

         NSMutableArray *artworkImages = [NSMutableArray array];
         for (AVMetadataItem *i in artworks)
         {
             NSString *keySpace = i.keySpace;
             UIImage *im = nil;

             if ([keySpace isEqualToString:AVMetadataKeySpaceID3])
             {
                 NSDictionary *d = [i.value copyWithZone:nil];
                 im = [UIImage imageWithData:[d objectForKey:@"data"]];
             }
             else if ([keySpace isEqualToString:AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes])
                 im = [UIImage imageWithData:[i.value copyWithZone:nil]];

             if (im)
                 [artworkImages addObject:im];
         }

         completion(artworkImages);
     }];
}
```

Comment: Thank you soooo much it works perfectly with a bit of modification!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Somehow it returns a non-empty array with number of elements - 0. What can I do ?

Comment: Perhaps you can clarify what you mean by a non-empty array with 0 elements?

Comment: Looking at this code again I can see what Jack meant by "a bit of modification"! I think I must have done a copy-and-paste-hatchett-job from some other code. Anyway the problem is that the information is loaded asynchronously but the array is returned synchronously. This method will never work as-is (in fact it shouldn't even compile!) -- you'll have to incorporate the substance of it into the asynchronous workflow in your app.

Comment: I tried to edit the answer to fix it (as this snippet of code is not working). Unfortunately, reviewers rejected my edit so I'm posting it below as a new answer.

Comment: You really don't need the loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys: part. You would be better off doing your own threading. Apple may change @"commonMetadata" in the future.

Comment: I've updated my code to be fully asynchronous and take a completion handler, largely because I couldn't disagree more with Nathaniel that you'd be better off doing your own threading! I also just noticed that Martin already did this in an answer below -- sorry Martin, I should have acted sooner.

Comment: Note that iOS 8 has changed the data returned. See here for updated code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25778757/getting-mp3-artwork-crashes-on-ios-8-but-works-on-ios-7/25794580#25794580

Answer (score 6):

This is just the answer of @hatfinch above but fixed and now working.

```
- (void)artworksForFileAtPath:(NSString *)path block:(void(^)(NSArray *artworkImages))block
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:url options:nil];
    NSArray *keys = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"commonMetadata", nil];
    [asset loadValuesAsynchronouslyForKeys:keys completionHandler:^{
         NSArray *artworks = [AVMetadataItem metadataItemsFromArray:asset.commonMetadata
                                                            withKey:AVMetadataCommonKeyArtwork
                                                           keySpace:AVMetadataKeySpaceCommon];

         NSMutableArray *artworkImages = [NSMutableArray array];
         for (AVMetadataItem *item in artworks) {
             NSString *keySpace = item.keySpace;
             if ([keySpace isEqualToString:AVMetadataKeySpaceID3]) {
                 NSDictionary *d = [item.value copyWithZone:nil];
                 [artworkImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[d objectForKey:@"data"]]];
             } else if ([keySpace isEqualToString:AVMetadataKeySpaceiTunes]) {
                 [artworkImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:[item.value copyWithZone:nil]]];
             }
         }
         if(block) {
             block(artworkImages);
         }
     }];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are merely wanting to access the artwork of the music already stored on the device *i.e from the iPod application*, then check out [this article](http://oleb.net/blog/2009/07/the-music-player-framework-in-the-iphone-sdk/) which demonstrates how to do it using existing frameworks provided by Apple, specifically the MediaPlayer framework.

If not, it may be wise to provide a little more information about what you are trying to achieve and also provide examples of the errors you are getting when trying to compile TagLib.

**EDIT:**

Another solution could be to use an embedded webview and use a JavaScript library such as [this one](http://www.sveinbjorn.org/javascript_mp3_id3_data_album_artwork) to load, parse and fetch the album artwork?

Comment: I'm not trying to get music from the iPod library - they're MP3 and M4A files stored in the applications documents directory. Most of the errors TagLib outputs are missing files (#include) - and I'm not quite sure where they could be. If there's any framework that can be directly imported into Xcode that may help - as I'm just dragging the folder into my project.

Comment: @jack-greenhill See if anything discussed on [this forum discussion](http://www.iphonedevbook.com/forum/iphone-development-questions/805-reading-mp3-id-tags.html) helps. It's using frameworks native to the iPhone to access ID3 data from custom MP3 files. Unless you have experience dealing with 3rd party libraries in this manner (*which from your question and comment suggests not*) I'd recommend staying away from anything that doesn't explicitly state it supports iOS and provides documentation on how to go about compiling; unfortunately TagLib does neither.

Comment: @jack-greenhill Like micpringle said ...3rd party libs ... If you really want to do it you might start here and follow the links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6578080/how-do-i-create-a-a-file-in-xcode-4/6580117#6580117

Comment: I don't mind using 3rd party libraries, as I think that there lies any hope of _actually getting any_ album art for a specific audio file. I'll have a look around and see if there are any ones that use Cocoa, and if not I'll investigate further into getting TagLib to compile for iOS.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting you don't use third party libraries, it's just your post and comments show a little naivety in that you thought you could *just* drag in the code and it'd compile. In my experience I've never found a third party library that didn't require at least a little manual setup such as tweaking of build settings (*header search paths, linker flags etc*), even those written in Obj-C.

Answer (score 1):

You could use this: https://github.com/EliaCereda/TagLib-ObjC